# Cannot GetView in Region (Prism 5.0)

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have 2 Module
In Module A:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion",typeof(uc_LogIn));
        this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("NavigatorRegion", typeof(uc_LogInNavigate));

        if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains("MainContainer"))
            Application.Current.Resources["MainContainer"] = this.Container;
        else
            Application.Current.Resources.Add("MainContainer", this.Container);
        if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains("MainRegionManager"))
            Application.Current.Resources["MainRegionManager"] = this.RegionManager;
        else
            Application.Current.Resources.Add("MainRegionManager", this.RegionManager);
    }
```

In a function in Module B:

```
private void OnLogout()
    {
        RegionManager regionManager = (RegionManager)Application.Current.Resources["MainRegionManager"];
        var view = regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].GetView("uc_LogIn");
    }
```

view" return null. So, How can i get a view in RegionManager without ViewName.

OR

How can i set ViewName in RegisterViewWithRegion function ?

Answer (score 0):

To your question:
How can i get a view in RegionManager without ViewName.

OR

How can i set ViewName in RegisterViewWithRegion function ?

you are getting "null" because "MainRegion" does not have any active veiws by that time.

```
var view = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].ActiveViews;
```

you would get readonly view of the collection of all the active views in the region.

But i think you wanted to ask OnLogout() how can you navigate to Login view (uc_Login)??
To navigates to the specific region Manager , you can do like this:

You can call the RequestNavigate method on the RegionManager, which allows you to specify the name of the region to be navigated. This convenient method obtains a reference to the specified region and then calls the RequestNavigate method, as shown in the preceding code example(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx).

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion",
                               new Uri("uc_LogIn", UriKind.Relative));
```